# Cannot build Flutter Application due to errors

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have installed all the dependencies necessary for my flutter application but it is still throwing the errors below. Iam using flutter version 3.10.5

../Downloads/flutter_windows_3.10.5-stable/flutter/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/_goldens_io.dart:12:8: Error: Error when reading '../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/test_api-0.6.1/lib/expect.dart': The system cannot find the file specified.

import 'package:test_api/expect.dart' show fail;
^
../Downloads/flutter_windows_3.10.5-stable/flutter/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/binding.dart:17:8: Error: Error when reading '../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/test_api-0.6.1/lib/expect.dart': The system cannot find the file specified.

I have also cleared my cache using flutter pub cache repair but still it is throwing an error

I tried to run the flutter application but it is throwing an error during compilation

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to resolve the error by removing the installed folder for flutter's 3.10.5 version and downgrading to 3.10.3