# C:/Users/metra/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/test_api-0.6.1/lib/expect.dart': The system cannot find the file specified. Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, testing

## Description

I'm currently working on a program, and the program was working fine. But when I added Firebase packages, it gave me this error. If I remove the packages, it works fine again.
As far as I understand, it couldn't find the expect.dart file in a package called test_api. Indeed, this file is not available in that specific version, but it exists in previous versions. I tried lowering the version, but the Flutter SDK relies on the newer version.
What's the solution? Thank you in advance

## the Error

```
/C:/Users/metra/flutter/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/binding.dart:17:8: Error: Error when reading '/C:/Users/metra/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/test_api-0.6.1/lib/expect.dart': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

## I'm trying to solve but still error occur

1. - delete pubspec.lock
   - run flutter clean
   - run flutter pub get
2. flutter pub cache repair
3. - flutter pub cache clean
   - flutter pub get
4. import test_api 0.5.1 instead of 0.6.1
   and not working Because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on test_api
   0.6.1 and myproject depends on test_api ^0.5.1, flutter_test
   from sdk is forbidden.

Comment: you can looking for this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/76625038)